# throw error inside rxjs Observable

Tags: javascript, error-handling, rxjs, reactive-programming

I'm trying to throw an error inside a rxjs Observable

```
 new Observable(subscriber => {
   Observable.throw("error1");
   return Observable.throw("error2");
 })
 .subscribe(
   () => {},
   err => console.error(err)
 );
```

error 1 is not caught.

error2 gives a compilation error:

```
Argument of type '(this: Observable<{}>, subscriber: Subscriber<{}>) => ErrorObservable<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: Observable<{}>, subscriber: Subscriber<{}>) => TeardownLogic'. Type 'ErrorObservable<string>' is not assignable to type 'TeardownLogic'
```

what is the proper way to throw an error inside an observable?

Comment: try throwing an error like `Observable.throw(new Error("error1"))`.

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja doesn't work. It isn't caught by the subscribe()

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [`Subscriber.error`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscriber.js~Subscriber.html#instance-method-error):

```js
new Rx.Observable(subscriber => {
  subscriber.error("error1");
  subscriber.error("error2"); // not called because a stream will be finalized after any error
})
.subscribe(
  () => {},
  err => console.error(err)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 7):

When using `new Observable()` or `Observable.create()` you can push the error directly to the subscriber (observer):

```
Observable.create(subscriber => {
   subscriber.error(new Error("error1"));
 })
 .subscribe(
   () => {},
   err => console.log(err.message)
 );
```

The anonymous function passed to `new Observable()` can optionally return an unsubscribe callback. That's why it gives you the error because you're returning an Observable.

Using `Observable.throw("error1")` is usually not necessary. This is just an Observable that only emits an error and nothing more. You could use it for example like the following:

```
Observable.create(subscriber => {
    subscriber.next('whatever');
  })
  .merge(Observable.throw(new Error("error2")))
  .subscribe(
    () => {},
    err => console.log(err.message)
  );
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/fivudu/edit?js,console

Comment: so are thrown errors inside a producer `throw new Error()` are effectively ignored and not reported?

Answer (score 5):

In v6 and higher you want to import `throwError`, that Observable.throw static method is an unfortunate necessity leftover from v5 compat.

```js
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
throwError('hello');
```

Source: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3733#issuecomment-391427430

Answer (score 2):

With an observable you created yourself, you have access to the `observer.error()` method.

```ts
const obs = Observable.create(observer => {

  // Emit a value.
  observer.next("hello");

  // Throw an error.
  observer.error("my error");

});
```

Note: if you're using RxJS 4, you'll have to use `onNext()` and `onError()` instead.